# How to use ncal:Journal and ncal:journalStatus?

Tags: discussion

I can't seem to find an example of how to use `ncal:Journal` and `ncal:journalStatus` to represent a journal entry?

Basically how to say a jounal entry belows to a specific `ncal:Journal` ?

https://oscaf.sourceforge.net/ncal.html#ncal:Journal